# How to update wso2is component

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use wso2is-5.10.0. There the bug in active limit session handler that was fixed recently (https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-basicauth/pull/77).
I want use new component **identity-local-auth-basicauth** build in my setup. What should I do? Is it enough to replace the file in `repository/components/dropins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wso2is-5.10.0, the relevant identity local auth basicauth release version is 6.3.0. So if you want to get that fix to wso2is-5.10.0, then you need to apply that fix to 6.3.0 [1] tag. Then build the jar and replace the file in repository/components/dropins/ location.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-basicauth/tree/v6.3.0/

Comment: Thanks!
That fix use FrameworkUtils.resolveUserIdFromUsername that not relevant to wso2is-5.10.0. So I need to apply all that new one by one or I can use whole build of authentication-framework?

Comment: Yes, you need to patch this as well https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/tree/v5.17.5

Comment: @Pubci how do I patch that the identity framework? I have a JAR to patch a specific component of the framework, but when I add it to dropins the changes still aren't reflected when I test it

Comment: Figured it out, for anyone else wondering I had to put my specific JAR in `lib/runtimes/cxf3/` and make sure to delete the older version of the JAR I was replacing